# Operands missing in MySQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

I'm getting an arguments error from the MySQL module looking for 4 operands. I just don't see which operands it's looking for. It works for some case types and not others. Line numbers of error (trimmed at bottom which refers to MySQL library):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christoph/PycharmProjects/physicianWorkQueueProject/physicianWorkQueueProject.py", line 158, in <module>
    parse()
  File "/Users/christoph/PycharmProjects/physicianWorkQueueProject/physicianWorkQueueProject.py", line 138, in parse
    c.execute(getPhysiciansql_cmd)
...
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 4 column(s)
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python
##################################################
# This is a prototype pathologist work queue management system
# The program calls out to a database of pathologists, their specialities,
# and an index of case types and their intended specialists
#
# Usage: Run at your command line. You will then enter case numbers (which aren't validated (currently))
# and case types (which are validated). The program will distribute the entered case as follows:
#
# If the case is intended for generalists, a system that amounts to names being pulled from a hat
# is employed. When a name is selected (at random), the case is entered into that pathologists' work queue.
# That pathologists' name is not returned to the pool.
# The cycle will then repeat with a random name picked every time, in this same way, for generalist-requiring cases,
# until the entirety of names have been pulled. At this point, all names are returned to the pool and the whole cycle
# begins again
#
# For the specialist requiring cases, the name-draw system is bypassed and the case is directly entered
# into the pathologists' work queue.

# 16 Aug 2018
# My Real Name
##################################################

import mysql.connector as mariaDB
import time
import pandas as pd
from random import choice


def distributefairly(inputCaseNumber, inputcasetype):
    # function distrbutefairly does a draw out of a hat, with each name being pulled and the pot shrinking until none are
    # left at which point all names are added back

    c.execute("SELECT physicianName FROM physicianNamesSpecialties;")
    originalPhysicianList = c.fetchall()
    physicianList = originalPhysicianList

    # print("counter at:",count)

    chosenPhysician = choice(physicianList)
    pos = physicianList.index(chosenPhysician)
    physicianList.pop(pos)
    cleanedUpChosenPhysician = chosenPhysician[0]
    insert(cleanedUpChosenPhysician)
    print("This case is going to", cleanedUpChosenPhysician + ".")
    select()

    increment()

    if len(physicianList) == 0:
        reset()


def reset():
    # this resets the counter the distributefairly module calls
    global count
    global physicianList
    count = 0
    c.execute("SELECT physicianName FROM physicianNamesSpecialties;")
    physicianList = c.fetchall()


def increment():
    # increments the counter of the distributefairly module
    global count
    count +=


def print_count():
    print(count)


def insert(cleanedUpPhysResult):
    # adds inputted cases into the workQueue table
    global inputCaseNumber
    global inputCaseType
    ts = time.gmtime()
    readableTs = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ts)
    c2.execute("INSERT INTO workQueue (name, caseNumber, timestamp, tableCaseType) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (cleanedUpPhysResult, inputCaseNumber, readableTs, str(inputCaseType)))
    conn2.commit()


def select():
    # this outputs the workQueue after every addition
    sql = "SELECT * FROM workQueue"
    c2.execute(sql)

    rWQ = c2.fetchall()

    print(pd.DataFrame(rWQ, columns= ['Name','Case Number','Time Stamp','Specialty','Row ID'])) # .set_index('Row ID')


def startup():

    # create()
    global inputCaseType
    global inputCaseNumber
    inputCaseNumber = input("Enter Case Number: ")
    inputCaseType = input("Enter case type (use proper abbreviations): ")


def parse():

    global inputCaseNumber
    global inputCaseType
    caseInputsql_cmd = "SELECT specialtyRequiredToProcess,Description FROM caseTypes WHERE caseTypeName='{}'".format(inputCaseType)

    c.execute(caseInputsql_cmd)
    rows_returned = c.fetchall()
    if not rows_returned:
        print("No match to table of specimen types returned. Check the case type abbreviation and try again.")
        return
    else:
        for row in rows_returned:
            r = row[0]
            d = row[1]
            print("This is a", r, "service case. It is a", d,"type case.")

        if r != "GENERALIST":
            getPhysiciansql_cmd = "SELECT physicianName FROM physicianNamesSpecialties WHERE (specialty, specialty2, specialty3, specialty4) ='{}'".format(r)
            c.execute(getPhysiciansql_cmd)
            physResult = choice(c.fetchall())
            cleanedUpPhysResult = physResult[0]
            print("This case is going to", cleanedUpPhysResult+".")
            insert(cleanedUpPhysResult)
            select()

        else:
            distributefairly(inputCaseNumber, inputCaseType)


conn = mariaDB.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxxx',password='xxxxxx',db='lookupDB')
conn2 = mariaDB.connect(host='xxxxxxl', user='xxxxx',password='xxxxxxx',db='workQueue')
c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn2.cursor()
count = 0

while True:

    startup()
    parse()
```

This line of code `.execute(...)` will fail:

```
getPhysiciansql_cmd = 
"SELECT physicianName FROM physicianNamesSpecialties WHERE (specialty, specialty2, specialty3, specialty4) ='{}'".format(r)
c.execute(getPhysiciansql_cmd)
```

My Var `r` holds this data:

```
print("This is a", r, "service case. It is a", d,"type case.")

This is a THORACIC service case. It is a TRANSBRONCHIAL WANG NEEDLE ASPIRATION type case.
```

My Var `getPhysiciansql_cmd` holds this data:

```
getPhysiciansql_cmd = SELECT physicianName FROM 

physicianNamesSpecialties WHERE (specialty, specialty2, specialty3, specialty4) ='THORACIC'
```

Comment: You need to tell us the exact line(s) where the problem is.  And you are in the best position to figure this out, not we.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christoph/PycharmProjects/physicianWorkQueueProject/physicianWorkQueueProject.py", line 158, in <module>
    parse()
"/Users/christoph/PycharmProjects/physicianWorkQueueProject/physicianWorkQueueProject.py", line 138, in parse
    c.execute(getPhysiciansql_cmd)

Rest follows up in the MySQL library.

Comment: What is `WHERE (s, s2, s3, s4) = '...'` supposed to accomplish? Do you mean something like `WHERE s = '...' OR s1 = '...' OR s2 = '...'`…?

Comment: So we have physicians who carry different services depending on the day or week. Today, Jim Bob is on Head and Neck, Billy is on Gynaecological. s is the primary service the person has, but s2, s3, s4 are alternate services the person could be on.

Comment: That's too abstract an explanation. If you had to write that query in plain English, what would it be asking?

Comment: I'm really sorry. Forgot I wasn't interfacing with my wife who works there :). These pathologists who are in a group, maybe 17 of them, all have specialties and subspecialties which they're certified in. Some of them share the same specialty. Since the practice tries to be fair, the goal is to have them rotate through the possible specialties so that they're not doing the same thing every day or week. So Billy does gynaecological cases, breast cases. Jimmy does thoracic cases but also head and neck cases. Each physician has up to 4 specialties and some just have one or two.

Comment: We're trying to have everything handed out fairly and automatically. For those cases not requiring a specialist (i.e. are generalist cases), we are doing a pull from the hat approach. We want to do the same with the specialist cases. For those physicians who share the same specialty, we want to pick fairly from who's capable of servicing that case. So the query is "give me the physician name from this table who can do that case of the requisite type". Requisite type is based on the entry of the user, which is matched on a list which dictates specialist required vs generalist.

Comment: You're still speaking to your wife, not programmers. I want to hear something like "...where r equals speciality or speciality2 or speciality3 ...". The query you wrote is, pardon, nonsense, and it's unclear what its intention is. You're explaining this three levels too far removed from this very localised case.

Comment: Okay. Let me try again.  In English I would say, "Select the physician name (physicianName) from the table (physicianNamesSpecialties) where R (the result of the lookup of specialist vs generalist) matches any of the specialties in these fields (specialty, specialty2, specialty3, specialty4)."

Comment: The first lookup to figure out generalist vs specialist is this: caseInputsql_cmd = "SELECT specialtyRequiredToProcess,Description FROM caseTypes WHERE caseTypeName='{}'".format(inputCaseType). After some processing, I assign this to R. R is then used with the statement I wrote in plain English above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a matter of how I'm using the WHERE clause. I saw somewhere that the WHERE with multiple fields is written, you use parens around the fields. I've experimented in reducing this to the bare minimum  and using the OR operator in the WHERE clause and I have successfully received a proper response.

```
import mysql.connector as mariaDB

conn = mariaDB.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxx',password='xxxxx',db='lookupDB')
conn2 = mariaDB.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxx',password='xxxxxx',db='workQueue')
c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn2.cursor()

inputSpecialty = input("specialty? ")
r = inputSpecialty


c.execute("SELECT physicianName FROM physicianNamesSpecialties WHERE specialty = %s OR specialty2 = %s OR specialty3 = %s OR specialty4 = %s", (r,r,r,r))

physResult = c.fetchall()

cleanedUpPhysResult = physResult
print(cleanedUpPhysResult)
```

Output:

```
specialty? THORACIC
[('Song',), ('Han',), ('He',), ('Goldfischer',)]
```